# How do I force Nginx to redirect a page to another url?

Tags: nginx

Im trying to do a nginx redirect so that areas.test.com goes to index.test1.com/home

So far i've got

```
location / {
rewrite areas.test.com index.test1.com/home redirect;
}
```

But for some reason this isnt working.

What do I need to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this:

```
server
{
    listen 12.34.56.78:80;
    server_name areas.test.com;
    location /
        {
        rewrite    ^ http://index.test1.com/home$request_uri? permanent;
        }
}
```

The $request_uri? parameter is optional, useful if you'd like to shift over POST requests.

The 'permanent' parameter gives the requester a 301 response code.
To understand the difference between 301 and 302, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
server {
    server_name areas.test.com;
    location / {
        return 301 $scheme://index.test1.com/home$request_uri;
    }
}
```

"return" should be a bit faster than "rewrite".

Comment: "return should be a bit faster than "rewrite". Yes, could be, but from my experience, since a website w/ 5 million visits a month can be handled by Nginx as the proxy for multiple workers behind by a very small machine (2cores, 2GB RAM), the 'bit faster' argument isn't so important.